# how to declare a byte[] in C# so that ironpython interprets it as byte[] and not as a tuple

Tags: c#, ironpython, arrays, tuples, dynamic-language-runtime

In a C++/CLI we have a function that returns this:

```
array<Byte>^ OutBuffer = gcnew array<Byte>(BufferSize);
```

IronPython treats it as a `byte[]`.

In C#, we have a function that returns this:

```
OutBuffer = new Byte[InBuffer.Length];
```

While a C# client treats Outbuffer as a `byte[]`, IronPython treats it as a tuple containing multiple arrays.

How do we make IronPython relate to `OutBuffer` as a `byte[]` and not as a tuple?

Why the discrepancy between the C# and C++/CLI?

EDIT: This question is posed and apparently solved, but no answer supplied. Can this be corrected?

Comment: How do you know it's treating it was a tuple?  I would suspect if anything it's getting converted to a tuple along the way.

Comment: I think you are right, Dino. In the C# code, the OutBuffer was being passed by reference explicitly. Once we got rid of reference, it works.

Comment: I would be extremely useful MrT if you could append this question to show what exactly you did in Python and how you solved the problem.  I have a similar issue and your question doesn't help with any answer - please extend it to help the SO community

Comment: if you found out the awnser yourself, you can post an awnser to your own question and then mark that as the awnser.